# Javascript "Uncaught type errors"

Tags: javascript, playlist

The following errors prevent the application from working:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeAttribute' of null" 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"
```

The app should play the video playlist as soon as it's loaded. The playlist will play if you click on the second video and then click back on the first video. 
I get the same error regardless if I place

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/playlist_jquery.js"></script>
```

between the HEAD tags or right before the closing BODY tag

Here's an example: 
http://bit.ly/10QO0mv

Any insight would be helpful.

Thanks - 
Derek

Comment: I'd suggest looking for calls to `removeAttribute` and `appendChild` and ensuring that the element they're trying to work on exists.

Comment: Your example has a load of minified code. No-one is going to dig through that.
Whatever object you're calling `removeAttribute` or `appendChild` on, are `null`. The error has all the information you need.

Comment: Cerbus I would never expect anyone to go through all the minified code. I'm still pretty new at this so I am just looking for some insight, that's all.

Comment: I was able to resolve the error. I overlooked a setting in the Sublime Video player. If you click on the link above it will autoplay the videos in the playlist. I appreciate everyone's comments and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code inside an onload event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    ...
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Maybe your script is being executed before the page is completely loaded and, therefore, the `getElementById()` method returns `null`

Comment: You're probably right. The script that outputs the playlist and video is all in php. Should I put the php code in a separate page and call the new page from the window.onLoad event?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What are you suggesting to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try start playing of video once body is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // start video streaming once all resources are done loading
 });
```

Comment: the video streaming code is executed using php in the body. what exactly would I call in the ready function?

Answer (score 0):

The videos now play once the page is loaded. I overlooked a setting in the SublimeVideo player. Basically, you can't reference the 'sublime' class in the video tag on the first video in a playlist.